# Setting a tag to a Retrofit Call in order to cancel by tag later

Tags: android, call, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using a Retrofit service interface that generates my Call objects, very much like the example one they show:

```
public interface GitHubService {
    @GET("users/{user}/repos")
    Call<List<Repo>> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
}
```

I would like to be able to cancel all Call objects generated by the listRepos method that have been enqueued or are running. I see that I can add a tag to the Call object's Request builder, but how can I swap the Request on a Call? It does not seem like I can modify the Request of a Call after it has already been created.

Comment: Have you find answer for this?

Comment: @Dhrupal Have you find the solution for this one. Even I've the same requirement http://stackoverflow.com/q/42066885/4548981