# Retrofit Adding tag to the original request object

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm trying to solve a problem where I'll be making a couple of asynchronous calls and based on the original request, I'm performing a task. To solve this issue, I'm trying to add a TAG to each request and then on successful response, I can get the tag and take action based on the tag. Here, I'm using TAG only to identify the original request.

**Problem**

Before calling the enqueue method, I'm setting the tag to the original request. But when I get the response in the successful callback, I'm getting different tag that I didn't set. Somehow the request object itself is coming as the tag object there. I'm not sure, how???

Please check the code below-

```
GitHubService gitHubService = GitHubService.retrofit.create(GitHubService.class);
                final Call<List<Contributor>> call = gitHubService.repoContributors("square", "retrofit");

                // Set the string tag to the original request object.
                call.request().newBuilder().tag("hello").build();


                call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Contributor>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<List<Contributor>> call, Response<List<Contributor>> response) {
                        Log.d("tag", response.raw().request().tag().toString());
                        // I'm getting Request{method=GET, url=https://api.github.com/repos/square/retrofit/contributors, tag=null} as the value of the tag. WHY????
                        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                        textView.setText(response.body().toString());
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<Contributor>> call, Throwable t) {
                        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                        textView.setText("Something went wrong: " + t.getMessage());
                    }
                });
```

Can somebody point out that what exactly I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

For me this code is working

```
val CLIENT: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
    addInterceptor(TagInterceptor())
}.build()

val SERVER_API: ServerApi = Retrofit.Builder()
    .client(CLIENT)
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()
    .create(ServerApi::class.java)

interface ServerApi {

    @GET("api/notifications")
    @Tag("notifications")
    suspend fun getNotifications(): ResponseBody
}

@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class Tag(val value: String)

internal class TagInterceptor : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()
        val builder = request.newBuilder()
        request.tag(Invocation::class.java)?.let {
            it.method().getAnnotation(Tag::class.java)?.let { tag ->
                builder.tag(tag.value)
            }
        }
        return chain.proceed(builder.build())
    }
}
```

Then cancel by tag

```
fun OkHttpClient.cancelAll(tag: String) {
    for (call in dispatcher().queuedCalls()) {
        if (tag == call.request().tag()) {
            call.cancel()
        }
    }
    for (call in dispatcher().runningCalls()) {
        if (tag == call.request().tag()) {
            call.cancel()
        }
    }
}

CLIENT.cancelAll("notifications")
```

Answer (score 6):

This solution is clearly a hack, but it works.

Let's say you create your Retrofit service like this :

```
 public <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {

    // Could be a simple "new"
    Retrofit.Builder retrofitBuilder = getRetrofitBuilder(baseUrl); 

    // Could be a simple "new"
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClientBuilder = getOkHttpClientBuilder();  

    // Build your OkHttp client
    OkHttpClient httpClient = httpClientBuilder.build();

    Retrofit retrofit = retrofitBuilder.client(httpClient).build();

    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
}
```

You will need to add a new `CallFactory` to your Retrofit instance, so it adds a tag every-time. Since the tag will be read-only, we will use an array of Object containing only one element, which you will be able to change later on.

```
Retrofit retrofit = retrofitBuilder.client(httpClient).callFactory(new Call.Factory() {
        @Override
        public Call newCall(Request request) {

            request = request.newBuilder().tag(new Object[]{null}).build();

            Call call = httpClient.newCall(request);

            // We set the element to the call, to (at least) keep some consistency
            // If you want to only have Strings, create a String array and put the default value to null;
            ((Object[])request.tag())[0] = call;

            return call;
        }
    }).build();
```

Now, after creating your call, you will be able to change the contents of your tag:

```
((Object[])call.request().tag())[0] = "hello";
```

Comment: ok tag is set, how to find this request later on, say, to be able to cancel it?

Answer (score 0):

The request already have tag on it . You can get it form this code：

```
val invocation: Invocation? = call.request().tag(Invocation::class.java)
        if (invocation != null) {
            Timber.d("tag--${invocation.method().name}}-------${invocation.arguments()}")
        }
```